# Competition: best (most informative, beautiful etc.) screenshots on GIS SE

Tags: discussion, votes, images

Just an idea about how to enhance the awareness for the quality of questions and answers. In special, I think about screenshots. A good screenshot/image is often already half of a good question or answer. Unfortunately, there are often no images or screenshots where a question or answer would clearly benefit of including one.

Images/screenshots are crucial elements of many questions and answers, but do not get any special awareness: an up-/downvote or accept is for the question or answer as a whole and we never know how a screenshot contributed to that.

So I propose to rise the awareness of how a good image or screenshot could look like. Could we make kind of a competition to select the best (or: a selection/ranking of one of the best) screenshots posted on GIS SE? "Best" could mean different things and we could possibly define different categories: 1) most informative (excellant example of how to explain a problem/illustrate a solution), 2) most beautiful (aesthetic), etc. Those could be linked here in Meta as "best practice" for those who would like to improve their skills in asking or answering.

What's your opinion about that? Maybe there are other parts of an answer (e.g. documentation/links?) that would be worth of a little competition, apart from just upvoting whole questions/answers?

Comment: Might be subjective, but you could start by linking to some good examples